# Haskell in GHCI: Why do I need parens to make this pattern match work?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

So using GHCI, these statements are equivalent which makes sense to me because the list expression in end0 is syntactic sugar for the list expression in end1:

```
let end0 [x,y,z] = z

let end1 (x:y:z:[]) = z
```

But taking the parens out of the pattern of end1 gives me an "Parse error in pattern" error. So why is that? Do the parens have special meaning in a pattern match or is it a precedence issue like I normally think of when I use parens with operators?

Comment: Note: That's not specific to GHCi.

Comment: Ah, should I remove the GHCI tag and make it Haskell only? I guess to me its still related because I normally use these constructs in GHCI.

Comment: You do not normally do pattern-matching outside of GHCi? Because this is true of any match that involves a constructor.

Comment: No, its just I thought about this question when I was in GHCi so originally I thought my problems were GHCI specific, until corrected by the first comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has to do with precedence.

A function takes precedence over :, so GHC would infer that you are defining the function for x only. That's why you have to pack it all inside parens.

Comment: Function application takes precedence over *everything*

Comment: Well, except record update... people generally pretend that isn't true though.

Comment: From The Gentle Introduction To Haskell: "Function application has higher precedence than any infix operator". http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/haskell/haskell-intro-html/functions.html

Answer (score 6):

Because without the parens, it's parsed as `let (end1 x):y:z:[] = z`.